# How is Gene sequence files i.e FASTA files so compressible?

Tags: binary

Why are Gene squencing file i.e FASTA files so compressible. It was stated on a site that few compression algorithms are capable of compressing  these files to Gigabytes (from Terabytes).

 And is it possible to convert binary data to FASTA file for high compression.

 Is there any difference between algorithms used in compression of FASTA files and normal binary files.

Comment: There's lots of obviously ridiculous claims that are "stated on a site". Most of them are not even worth bothering to refute. There are also lots of correct claims which are wildly misinterpreted, either because the misinterpretation is emotionally satisfying or because the claim is badly written or both. In the post-truth era, it is even less credible to repeat a quote without an accurate citation. Personally, I find this claim to be highly doubtful, although if it's talking about lossy compression (with a lot of lost details), it's possible. Please provide a citation. Thanks.

Comment: @rici I read it here https://www.nature.com/articles/srep11565 and wikia, and other few sites too.

Comment: @rici I was thinking if there is any method which can be applied to normal binary files too.

Comment: Also note that you can get very high compression ratios if the original was encoded in an inefficient format, like XML  The bulk of a FASTA consists of only four different characters (AGTC), so you can trivially remove 75% of the bits (IIRC, that's roughly the same ratio as zip gives you.)

Comment: @rici Thanks. And so order of magnitude compression is not possible for normal files. right ?

Comment: That paper is not about compressing individual genome sequences; it's about compressing large collections of genome sequences. Since the various sequences are extremely similar, you can compress the collection by storing only the differences. Github effectively does the same thing to compress all of the versions of a software project. But that doesn't give you anything you can use to radically compress a single file

Comment: If you want to pursue compression theory, start by finding a copy of [Claude Shannon's fundamental text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Mathematical_Theory_of_Communication) and read it carefully. Hopefully you have access to an academic library.

Comment: Please don't provide additional information in the comments.  Instead, revise the question so it provides the relevant background and context and citations, reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and makes the question interesting and useful for others.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have rightly pointed out, you can't get around the pigeonhole principle. Given any compression algorithm, half of all possible files of a randomly chosen length cannot be compressed by even one bit.

(On the other hand, of course, no file needs to be *expanded* by more than one bit, because you can always store it verbatim.)

If you understand the nature of the data that is being represented in FASTA files, and how it is represented, you will be able to see why it should be very easy to compress them.

FASTA files are plain-text, designed for easy processing using text-based tools. So there is opportunity for some compression already there. Here is an example of the start of one:

```
>NC_045512.2 Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 isolate Wuhan-Hu-1, complete genome
ATTAAAGGTTTATACCTTCCCAGGTAACAAACCAACCAACTTTCGATCTCTTGTAGATCTGTTCTCTAAA
CGAACTTTAAAATCTGTGTGGCTGTCACTCGGCTGCATGCTTAGTGCACTCACGCAGTATAATTAATAAC
TAATTACTGTCGTTGACAGGACACGAGTAACTCGTCTATCTTCTGCAGGCTGCTTACGGTTTCGTCCGTG
TTGCAGCCGATCATCAGCACATCTAGGTTTCGTCCGGGTGTGACCGAAAGGTAAGATGGAGAGCCTTGTC
CCTGGTTTCAACGAGAAAACACACGTCCAACTCAGTTTGCCTGTTTTACAGGTTCGCGACGTGCTCGTAC
GTGGCTTTGGAGACTCCGTGGAGGAGGTCTTATCAGAGGCACGTCAACATCTTAAAGATGGCACTTGTGG
CTTAGTAGAAGTTGAAAAAGGCGTTTTGCCTCAACTTGAACAGCCCTATGTGTTCATCAAACGTTCGGAT
GCTCGAACTGCACCTCATGGTCATGTTATGGTTGAGCTGGTAGCAGAACTCGAAGGCATTCAGTACGGTC
GTAGTGGTGAGACACTTGGTGTCCTTGTCCCTCATGTGGGCGAAATACCAGTGGCTTACCGCAAGGTTCT
```

The first line is a header (denoted by the `>` character) which describes the sample that follows. In FASTA, this is free-form text, but in practice, they often follow a standard, starting with a machine-readable symbol (in this case, an [accession number](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/acc_prefix/)) and human-readable text following.

Following that header line is the data. FASTA files can contain a number of types of data, such as DNA, RNA, and protein sequences. It can be used to store anything from collections of raw reads out of a sequencing machine, to assembled genomes. There are also ways to encode methylation. But for this use case, we are talking about fully assembled genomes, so let's stick to that.

For reference genomes, there are exactly five possible characters that can occur: A, C, G, T, and N, with the first four representing the four nucleotides and N meaning unknown.

The line length in the data section is not semantically important, and so does not need to be preserved.

Now let's look at a more complex example of a eukaryote, which has multiple chromosomes. The FASTA data will typically look like this:

```
>NC_000001.11 Homo sapiens chromosome 1, GRCh38.p13 Primary Assembly
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
[many lines of N deleted]
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTAACCCTAAC
CCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTA
ACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCC
TAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACC
CTAACCCTAACCCCTAACCCTAACCCTAAACCCTAAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCC
[etc etc]
>NC_000002.12 Homo sapiens chromosome 2, GRCh38.p13 Primary Assembly
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
[more lines of just N deleted]
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCGTATCCCAC
ACACCACACCCACACACCACACCCACACACACCCACACCCACACCCACACACACCACACCCACACACCAC
ACCCACACCCACACACCACACCCACACCACACCCACACACCACACACCACACCCACACCCACACACACCA
CACCCACACACCACACCCACACACACCCTAACCCTAACCCCTAACCCCTAACCCTAACCCTACCCGAACC
CTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCCTAACCCTAACCCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCGTAACCCTAACCCTTTACCC
TAACCCGAACCCCTAACCCCTAACCCCTAACCCTTAACCCTAACCCTTAACCCTGACCCTGACCCTGACC
[lots of lines deleted]
>NC_012920.1 Homo sapiens mitochondrion, complete genome
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGG
GTATGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTGGAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTC
CTGCCTCATCCTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACTTACTAAAGTGTGTTA
ATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTGAATGTCTGCACAGCCACTTTCCACACAGACATC
ATAACAAAAAATTTCCACCAAACCCCCCCTCCCCCGCTTCTGGCCACAGCACTTAAACACATCTCTGCCA
[more lines deleted; you get the idea]
```

Within one organism, the headers are extremely predictable. There is a record number, which is a closed vocabulary, followed by text which is also highly regular. This suggests separating the headers and the data payloads and compressing them as separate streams.

When `N`s occur, they overwhelmingly occur in long runs in specific places; in this case, at the start of the chromosomes (though not the mitochondrion; chloroplasts in plants would be similar). This is because chromosomes have a 3D shape, and some parts are more difficult to "access" than others, such as the [centromere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centromere). As such, they are not only much harder to sequence, they also play essentially no known role in biology apart from geometric.

After the run of `N`s, we have a section that is highly repetitive, and therefore highly compressible. This is known as the [telomere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomere), and it plays a vital function: it is a kind of redundant code that signals that this is the end of a strand, rather than a break, so the cell's DNA repair mechanisms don't try to repair it.

It's not obvious from this sample, but A, C, G, and T do not occur with equal probability. In *homo sapiens*, the "GC content" (i.e. the proportion of nucleotides that are G or C) is between 38% and 48%, depending on the chromosome.

So what I hope you can see here is that there is a *lot* of things that can be exploited in compressing the data payload.

Finally, and perhaps most crucially, as the comments rightly point out, when you are storing [a library of human genomes](https://www.humanvariomeproject.org/) (and the same reasoning applies to human genetic disease samples, or human cancer samples), samples from different organisms tend to have a lot in common, so it makes sense to either store differences from a single reference, or combine as many references as possible into a single model (e.g. a k-mer set or de Bruijn graph; note that it may be efficient to use a different model for each type of chromosome) and use that for compression.

These models can be stored using extremely compact representations. See, for example:

- Conway and Bromage, *[Succinct data structures for assembling large genomes](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/27/4/479/198367)*, Bioinformatics 27:4, 2011, pp479–486.
- Bowe et al, *[Succinct de Bruijn graphs](https://alexbowe.com/succinct-debruijn-graphs/)*, in: *Algorithms in Bioinformatics*. WABI 2012. LNCS 7534.
- Rahman et al, *[Disk compression of k-mer sets](https://almob.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13015-021-00192-7)*, *Algorithms for Molecular Biology* 16:10, 2021.

Given such a model, you can use this to compress sequences using a method like [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_by_partial_matching).

So what I hope you can see from all this is that there is a lot of information that we can exploit to compress DNA reference sequences. FASTA files are designed for tool convenience, not compact storage, so even standard text compression techniques work reasonably well. But you can get even more compression using domain-specific information, including knowledge of biology.

Final thing: In the interest of full disclosure, I'm a co-author of one of the papers cited above.